# AngularJS Databind odata to kendoui diagram

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

I am trying to databind ASP.NET web api odata v3 to kendoui diagram control. It works OK with local data source but I am getting error when trying to use odata

Error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__count' of undefined

HTML

```
<div kendo-diagram="diagram" k-options="options" />
```

AngularJS

```
 $scope.options = {
                dataSource: {
                    type: "odata",
                    transport: {
                        read: {
                            url: "odata/Entities",
                            dataType: "json",
                            type: "GET"
                        }
                    }
                },              
                shapeDefaults: {
                    visual: visualTemplate 
                },
                layout: {
                    type: "tree"
                },
                schema: {    
                    data: "value"                                        
                }
            };



function visualTemplate(options) {
            var dataviz = kendo.dataviz;
            var g = new dataviz.diagram.Group();
            var dataItem = options.dataItem;

            g.append(new dataviz.diagram.Rectangle({
                width: 210,
                height: 75,
                stroke: {
                    width: 0
                },
                fill:  "green" 
            }));

            g.append(new dataviz.diagram.TextBlock({
                text: dataItem.Name, 
                x: 85,
                y: 20,
                color: "#fff"
            }));

            return g;
        }
```

json

```
{
  "odata.metadata":"http://localhost/TestSPA/odata/$metadata#Entities","odata.count":"5","value":[
    {
      "EntityRef":7,"Name":"Test"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone having the same issue: schema should be declared on the on the data source.

```
$scope.options = {
                dataSource: {
                    type: "odata",
                    transport: {
                        read: {
                            url: "odata/Entities",
                            dataType: "json",
                            type: "GET"
                        }
                    }, schema: {
                         data: function (data) {
                               return data.value;
                         },
                         total: function (data) {
                                return data['odata.count'];
                         }
                    }
                },              
                shapeDefaults: {
                    visual: visualTemplate 
                },
                layout: {
                    type: "tree"
                }

            };
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the exception is coming from the fact that the total variable that is coming from the server is no longer inside a field called **__count**.

I suspect that it is called in a different way in that newer version of the protocol. So you might need to specify it explicitly (via **schema.total**) pretty much the same way as shown [here](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-examples-asp-net/blob/master/grid-webapi-odata-crud/ProductService/index.html).

i.e.

```
       schema: {
          total: function (e) {
              return Number(e["odata.count"]);
          },
```

Comment: I have added total and I am still getting the same error. Would you have any other suggestions?